# transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server(provider:TCP Provider, error: 0-The semaphore timeout period has expired)

Tags: ssrs-2008, k2

We have an application server with the following spec’s:

• Windows 2008 R2 operating system.

• All prerequisites are configures successfully and correctly: Windows roles, MSDTC and connection to SQL DB server.

• MS Reporting Services 2008 R2 are installed and configured successfully, and all reports are deployed and render with no problems.

The application server connects to SQL Server 2008 R2 DB on different server - there are no firewalls between the 2 servers , and using UDL file, the connection is always successful using windows authentication or SQL authentication on SQL Server.

When we install “K2 blackpearl 4.5 (4.10060.1.0) with Update KB001040”, the setup completes successfully but the following exception appears when we open work list, when K2 setup manager is opened for reconfiguration and when rendering any report on the report manager: “A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired.)” although all DB’s are created successfully during the installation for K2. Also all other features at K2 (any feature at Management Console)  and Report Manager (deployment of reports, management of data sources, and folder/report settings) works perfectly.

When we remove K2 components from the server the reporting services works successfully again, without any reconfiguration.

We tried to move the server to new environment to check if there is a problem with the server itself, all installation and configuration are completed with no problems and the error message disappeared.

We did check all of below points:

• MSDTC configuration.

• All ports are open between the 2 servers.

• SQL connection is always successful between the 2 servers.

• We have a third server with MOSS 2007 installed and it works perfectly with problems in connection to DB.

• All users used for windows services and  SQL windows connection are active and configured correctly.

o Have SQL login with dbcreator and SecurityAdmin roles.

o Are added as Administrators on Application server.

• We have tries Windows authentication and SQL authentication and they all gave the same problem.

• We have used a newer version of K2 installation files “K2 blackpearl 4.5 (4.10060.1.0) with KB001320” and it failed at the last steps of installation with the same problem.

Please help on this.

Answer (score 1):

(full disclosure i work for K2) and looked through our system as well as the support forum and could not find a reference to this error.  From the people i talked to it appears to be a general network issue, with quite a few possible causes, including something as simple as the network card.  Although I am not 100% clear on a few points you made.  When you said

"following exception appears when we open work list" Where are you opening the worklist from?

When you said 
"When we remove K2 components from the server the reporting services works successfully again, without any reconfiguration."

Are you getting this error in SQL Reporting Services?

You can also post a question in http://k2underground.com someone else may have seen this.

**Edit** I asked around and there does not seem to be any good answers to this at the moment.  Would you be willing to open a K2 support ticket and let us look at the K2 logs or see the config via livemeeting?  Thanks!

Comment: For the point "Where I 'am opening the worklist?" I open it in the Workspace, everything works fine except the worklist and the reports. and the same exception appears when i open any report deployed on the reporting manager on the same server. I get the error on both applications. I will give it a try and post the problem on K2 underground.